# How to generate a 'stub' Python interface for a 3p library for development?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-typing, python-bindings

I'm developing for RPi. I'd like to do the majority of my coding on a fast, local machine with a snappy IDE. To do this, I need to be able to `pip install` the same modules as I have on the RPi. Problem is, one of the most popular, [RPi.GPIO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-gpio-python/) is only installable on the RPi for obvious reasons (my laptop doesn't have GPIO pins!)

As the library is primarily written in C, it's not easy to extract a Python interface from it. Is there any tool that can scan the C/compiled module and extract the Python interface, stubbed, and output that somewhere I can then easily import it?

I'd like to contribute back to the project and have a stubbed Python interface, that is installable on non-rpis so that development is easy.

Having never released a Python library before, some bonus points for pointers to how to 'teach' pip to download different packages on different OSs.

[Here's a ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/215/) of the issue I'd like to resolve.

Comment: [mypy's stubgen](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html) can be a starting point to generate an interface skeleton. You'll have to fix the function signature arity and parameter types in the skeleton.

Comment: I tried stubgen actually but the output interface seemed to make pylint etc v angry - is there any way to fully automate this without any human intervention so it could be included into a build script?